# Why real POS-terminals don't using PSE (2PAY or 1PAY)?

Tags: smartcard, emv

I experimented with two real terminals, via EMV contact (not contactless) way, and no one using PSE or PPSE to obtain a AID, as defined in EMV specification.

Both terminals just directly trying a set of AIDs with SELECT command until ICC will answer successfully.

Comment: not sure if this is on-topic, as I guess no one but the developerss who wrote this software can answer the question.

Comment: PSE is 1PAY and PPSE is 2PAY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EMV Defined two methods of Application Selection :

1. Selection via PSE/PPSE
2. Selection via Direct AID Method

For Contact Transaction, use of PSE is optional. Since you mentioned that you observed this behavior on Contact interface, so for that terminal is using Selection via Direct AID Method not with PSE (Since PSE is optional)

For Contactless interface presence of PPSE is mandatory. PPSE will be the first contactless application on the contactless card selected by merchant terminal.

To know more about Application selection, you can refer EMV Book 1 Section 12..!!

Answer (score 2):

the use of payment system environment was not mandatory in the earlier days. and people normally prefer complying to mandates and put to production asap. implementing pse was optional and implementing optional features(on card and terminal applications) will require development time, and you have to deal with bugs which comes with it. recently Mastercard and visa has mandated the used of ppse for contatctless, going forward it may come for contact too, hope you will encounter more in future.

Comment: I already wrote some soft which should work with maximum of cards. And it works via PPSE, without finding AIDs. Should I update it with implementing the finding of AIDs if no PPSE/PSE? **Warning - this soft uses NFC only**

Comment: terminal can query ppse and will do SELECT on the AID in PPSE if that AID is supported. in the other case where terminal does explicit SELECTs where you will return File not found found in all non matching cases and successful in case of applications in card. so you would have already implemented it I guess..

Comment: " in the other case where terminal does explicit SELECTs where you will return File not found found in all non matching cases and successful in case of applications in card" NO, i'm not yet implemented it!